# Upgrading Spring Boot from 1.3.7 to 1.4.0 causing NullPointerException in AuthenticatorBase.getJaspicProvider

Tags: spring, spring-boot, tomcat8

This is somewhat caused by the tomcat-embed-core version 8.5.4 that comes with the spring-boot-starter-jersey. It generates an error shown below on all integration tests. It will only work if I override the pom to use tomcat-embed-core version 8.0.36. What's weird is, that's the only error message I get.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.getJaspicProvider(AuthenticatorBase.java:1140)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:431)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:1110)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:785)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1425)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Here's my dependecy tree:

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:tree (default-cli) @ sample-services ---
[INFO] com.sample:sample-services:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- com.sample:sample-customer:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.sample:sample-core:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:1.4.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:1.4.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.8.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:1.4.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:jar:8.5.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-juli:jar:8.5.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.3.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.0.9.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.4.01:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:5.0.9.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- javax.transaction:javax.transaction-api:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:1.10.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.3.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:4.3.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:1.4.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.21:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.21:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.21:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.h2database:h2:jar:1.4.192:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.postgresql:postgresql:jar:9.4.1209.jre7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax:javaee-api:jar:7.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.sun.mail:javax.mail:jar:1.5.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.joda:joda-money:jar:0.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.sun.jna:jna:jar:3.0.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch:jar:1.4.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.data:spring-data-elasticsearch:jar:2.0.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.3.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:1.12.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:jar:2.3.4:compile
[INFO] |  |        +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:jar:5.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |        +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-backward-codecs:jar:5.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |        +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-analyzers-common:jar:5.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |        +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-queries:jar:5.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |        +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-memory:jar:5.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |        +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-highlighter:jar:5.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |        +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-queryparser:jar:5.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |        |  \- org.apache.lucene:lucene-sandbox:jar:5.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |        +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-suggest:jar:5.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |        |  \- org.apache.lucene:lucene-misc:jar:5.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |        +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-join:jar:5.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |        |  \- org.apache.lucene:lucene-grouping:jar:5.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |        +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-spatial:jar:5.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |        |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-spatial3d:jar:5.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |        |  \- com.spatial4j:spatial4j:jar:0.5:compile
[INFO] |  |        +- org.elasticsearch:securesm:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |        +- com.carrotsearch:hppc:jar:0.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  |        +- org.joda:joda-convert:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |        +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-smile:jar:2.8.1:compile
[INFO] |  |        +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:jar:2.8.1:compile
[INFO] |  |        +- io.netty:netty:jar:3.10.5.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |        +- com.ning:compress-lzf:jar:1.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |        +- com.tdunning:t-digest:jar:3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |        +- org.hdrhistogram:HdrHistogram:jar:2.1.6:compile
[INFO] |  |        +- commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |        \- com.twitter:jsr166e:jar:1.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:19.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.sf.uadetector:uadetector-core:jar:0.9.22:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- net.sf.qualitycheck:quality-check:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:2.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.annotation:jsr250-api:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.sf.uadetector:uadetector-resources:jar:2014.10:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.8.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.sample:sample-messaging:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-sns:jar:1.11.24:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-sqs:jar:1.11.24:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jersey:jar:1.4.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.4.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.17:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:1.4.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:8.5.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:8.5.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:8.5.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:jar:1.4.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.3.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.3.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.3.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-server:jar:2.23.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:jar:2.23.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-jaxb:jar:2.23.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-api:jar:2.4.0-b34:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-utils:jar:2.4.0-b34:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.glassfish.hk2.external:aopalliance-repackaged:jar:2.4.0-b34:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-locator:jar:2.4.0-b34:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.20.0-GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet-core:jar:2.23.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet:jar:2.23.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.ext:jersey-spring3:jar:2.23.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2:jar:2.4.0-b34:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:config-types:jar:2.4.0-b34:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-core:jar:2.4.0-b34:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-config:jar:2.4.0-b34:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-runlevel:jar:2.4.0-b34:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.glassfish.hk2:class-model:jar:2.4.0-b34:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- org.glassfish.hk2.external:asm-all-repackaged:jar:2.4.0-b34:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.glassfish.hk2:spring-bridge:jar:2.4.0-b34:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-json-jackson:jar:2.23.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.glassfish.jersey.ext:jersey-entity-filtering:jar:2.23.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-base:jar:2.8.1:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-json-provider:jar:2.8.1:compile
[INFO] |        \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:jar:2.8.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.8.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.8.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.8.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:1.4.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.2.4.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.3.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.3.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-s3:jar:1.11.24:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-kms:jar:1.11.24:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:jar:1.11.24:compile
[INFO] |     +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-cbor:jar:2.8.1:compile
[INFO] |     \- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.9.4:compile
[INFO] +- com.wordnik:swagger-jersey2-jaxrs_2.10:jar:1.3.13:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.wordnik:swagger-jaxrs_2.10:jar:1.3.13:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.wordnik:swagger-core_2.10:jar:1.3.13:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-scala_2.10:jar:2.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- com.thoughtworks.paranamer:paranamer:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jsonSchema:jar:2.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.wordnik:swagger-annotations:jar:1.3.13:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.json4s:json4s-ext_2.10:jar:3.2.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.json4s:json4s-native_2.10:jar:3.2.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.json4s:json4s-core_2.10:jar:3.2.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |     +- org.json4s:json4s-ast_2.10:jar:3.2.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |     \- org.scala-lang:scalap:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |        \- org.scala-lang:scala-compiler:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.json4s:json4s-jackson_2.10:jar:3.2.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.reflections:reflections:jar:0.9.9:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- com.google.code.findbugs:annotations:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-multipart:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.jvnet.mimepull:mimepull:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] +- org.glassfish.jersey.ext:jersey-bean-validation:jar:2.23.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.hk2.external:javax.inject:jar:2.4.0-b34:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:jar:2.23.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged:jersey-guava:jar:2.23.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.glassfish.hk2:osgi-resource-locator:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.el:javax.el-api:jar:2.2.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.web:javax.el:jar:2.2.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.jayway.restassured:rest-assured:jar:2.9.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:jar:2.4.7:test
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-xml:jar:2.4.7:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:jar:4.5.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup:tagsoup:jar:1.2.1:test
[INFO] |  +- com.jayway.restassured:json-path:jar:2.9.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-json:jar:2.4.7:test
[INFO] |  |  \- com.jayway.restassured:rest-assured-common:jar:2.9.0:test
[INFO] |  \- com.jayway.restassured:xml-path:jar:2.9.0:test
[INFO] +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.21:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:1.4.0.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:1.4.0.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:1.4.0.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:1.10.19:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.3.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.3.2.RELEASE:test
[INFO] +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.2.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor:jar:1.4.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.json:json:jar:20140107:compile
[INFO] +- org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher-compiler-2.2:jar:2.2.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.scala-lang:scala-library:jar:2.10.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:jar:2.10.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.parboiled:parboiled-scala_2.10:jar:1.1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.parboiled:parboiled-core:jar:1.1.7:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap:concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools:jar:1.4.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:1.4.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:1.4.0.RELEASE:compile
```

And here's my Application class:

```
@EntityScan(basePackageClasses = { Application.class, Jsr310JpaConverters.class })
@EnableScheduling
@EnableAsync
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.sample")
public class Application extends Loggable implements AsyncConfigurer {

    /**
     * This forces the SNS topics to be created and/or linked.
     */
    @Autowired
    @SuppressWarnings("all")
    private TopicFactory topicFactory;

    /**
     * It all begins here.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication application = new SpringApplication(Application.class);
        application.setBanner(new SampleBanner());
        application.run(args);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the @Async executor.
     */
    @Override
    public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(4);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(4);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(0);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("Async-");
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the uncaught exception handler for @Async operations.
     */
    @Override
    public AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler getAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        return (e, method, params) -> log.error("Uncaught async error", e);
    }
}
```

If someone could point me out where to start or what's causing it to fail, it would be of great help.

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Possible fixes**:

1) Set authConfigFactory to default AuthConfigFactory implementation used by Tomcat 8.5 (example basic implementation):

```
package com.example;

import org.apache.catalina.authenticator.jaspic.AuthConfigFactoryImpl;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

import javax.security.auth.message.config.AuthConfigFactory;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (AuthConfigFactory.getFactory() == null) {
            AuthConfigFactory.setFactory(new AuthConfigFactoryImpl());
        }
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

or

2) Remove duplicated `AuthConfigFactory` class from your classpath. In my case there were two different implementations of the same class:

```
org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-core/8.5.4/tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar!/javax/security/auth/message/config/AuthConfigFactory.class
javax/javaee-api/7.0/javaee-api-7.0.jar!/javax/security/auth/message/config/AuthConfigFactory.class
```

`javaee-api-7.0.jar` has it's own `AuthConfigFactory` implementation which is not fully compatible with Tomcat 8.5 and causes that `NullPointerException` (in Tomcat's version there is constant which defines default jaspic implementation class)
Remove `javaee-api` dependency (or any other which contains different AuthConfigFactory implementation) from your gradle/mvn project (if you can)

or

3) Downgrade Tomcat to 8.0 or 7.0:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-use-tomcat-7

**Explanation**:

The problem is related with Tomcat upgrade (from 8.0.x to 8.5.x) which has been made during Spring Boot upgrade from 1.3.x to 1.4.
The problem is that Tomcat 8.5 introduces jaspic support (https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/jaspic.html) and provides it's own implementation of AuthConfigFactory. This implementation defines default jaspic auth factory implementation:

```
private static final String DEFAULT_JASPI_AUTHCONFIGFACTORYIMPL =
            "org.apache.catalina.authenticator.jaspic.AuthConfigFactoryImpl";
```

which is not defined in other implementations (e.g. that one from javaee-api-7.0) and causes `NullPointerException` because no AuthConfigFactory were instantiated.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I ended up excluding javaee-api-7.0 from my library.

Comment: Option #1 worked perfectly for me! Thanks @MaciejMarczuk for the choices and the full explanation.

Comment: Here's the release notes for 1.4 https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-1.4-Release-Notes

Comment: #2 worked for us. Moving a legacy app to SpringBoot and noticed we had multiple JavaEE versions on the classpath. With them all removed, everything works as it should.

Comment: I'd like to add that if you need for some reasons javaee-api (for example persistnce annotations), you could use javaee-web-api to avoid this problem.

Comment: For me worked the approach `3)` (downgraded _Tomcat_ to `8.0`). Changed tomcat version in `<dependencyManagement>` in `pom.xml` section, other two gave me runtime exceptions (had three different `javax` libraries versions).