# Spring boot - Tomcat - NullPointerException on AuthenticatorBase.getJaspicProvider

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-boot

After starting and surfing to

> http://localhost:8080/

I get this error in my browser

**Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Thu Feb 09 11:52:20 CET 2017
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
No message available**

And this error in my Spring console

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.getJaspicProvider(AuthenticatorBase.java:1192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:465) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:798) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1434) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_74]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_74]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_74]
```

Somehow I think the problem is in my User entity class

```
@Entity
@Document(collection = "users")
public class User implements Serializable, UserDetails {
@Id
private String id;

private String username;
private String firstname;
private String lastname;
private String email;
private String encryptedPassword;

@OneToMany(targetEntity = Role.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<Role> roles;

public User() {
}

public User(String username, String firstname, String lastname, String email, String encryptedPassword, List<Role> roles) {
    this.username = username;
    this.firstname = firstname;
    this.lastname = lastname;
    this.email = email;
    this.encryptedPassword = encryptedPassword;
    this.roles = roles;
}
```

My application.properties file

```
security.basic.enabled=true
spring.data.rest.base-path=/api
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://<link to mlab>
```

Pom.xml file

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        <version>RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <version>RELEASE</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-rest-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ma.glasnost.orika</groupId>
        <artifactId>orika-core</artifactId>
        <version>RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <version>RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: I think this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38802437/upgrading-spring-boot-from-1-3-7-to-1-4-0-causing-nullpointerexception-in-authen) will help you. Sorry i cant make comment yet.

Comment: @theodosis Yes, that fixed it! Thanks!